# How do I avoid this java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java

When I enter the full file path (C:\Users\djustinwebb\Documents\BlueJ Projects\LightHouse) for "search" and it attempts to open the file I get the error: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\djustinwebb\Documents\BlueJ Projects\LightHouse (Access is denied) (in java.io.FileInputStream)

I have input "invoicedata.txt" for search and it worked even though it doesn't read through the file properly but I would like to know why it won't work when I use the full file path. What do I need to do to use the full file path without running into this error?

```
public String searchCase()throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String fileLine = null;

    StringTokenizer stok = null;

    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(search));


    String whatever = null;



    while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        fileLine = inputFile.nextLine();
        stok = new StringTokenizer(fileLine,",");

        caseLCount++;

        while(stok.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            if(userWord.equals(stok.nextToken()))
            {
                caseWCount++;

                whatever += caseLCount + ".\n";
            }//end if
        }// end nested while
    }//end outer while
    inputFile.close();
    return whatever;
}// end searchCase()
```

Comment: Does the file really exist at that path?  Can you open the file from another program?  Try running your Java process in admin mode.

Comment: seems to be permission issue. the fact that it gave access denied means it did try to open the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to open and read a `directory`, which is `LightHouse` here. You are supposed to enter the file name in the file path as well, like this, `..\LightHouse\invoicedata.txt`.

If you want to distinguish between files and folders, use the `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` methods. You can get the contents of folders using the `list()` and `listFiles()` methods.